# Css cursor:pointer won't register and neither will width or height

Tags: css

My css:

```
.uploadify {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    width:264px;
    height:54px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

This should make the div on the attached html file (which has been saved as it is only accessibly by administrators of my site) the specified size, but it doesn't for some reason. How can I override this? Also my `cursor:pointer`s on other divs that are being hovered on aren't registering

http://client.henrybuilt.com/Upload%20Download%20Files.htm

Comment: The `.uploadify` element has width and height set by the `style` attribute, so that overrides the rule. And the visible border is generated by a different element, also with its own width and height. The cursor works for me for the region of `.uploadify`. Just check out you page with a Developer Console of your choice!

Comment: post as an answer and i'll accept. cant believe i missed that haha

Comment: [http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) -> [http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/width/](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/width/) / [http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/height/](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/height/). -_-

Comment: for compatibilty, I typically use both `cursor: pointer` and `cursor: hand`

Comment: @BrianPhillips: Gotta get that IE5 compatibility!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` and `height` properties are overriden by direct styling with the `style` attribute:

```
<div id="file_upload" class="uploadify" style="height: 30px; width: 120px;">
```

It's pretty easy to spot this kind of mistakes. You just need to open the Developer Console / Developer Tools / Inspector (available in at least in Firefox, IE and Chrome) and select the element in question. Then you will see all the applied styles to the element and their sources (i.e. the style attribute).